# Changing system date/time causes webview to hang

Tags: webview, gtk, webkitgtk

I have been using the debian [wheezy](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libwebkitgtk-1.0-0) target prebuilt library to write my own browser using GTK toolkit on top of X11 under linux. While experimenting with various timers I had hit a very strange issue. When I change the system date/time of the linux machine to some value in the past then all the timers that are running in the loaded webpage is getting affected.

***For example:*** If I load [this URL](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock) under my custom build browser, it works fine by showing the proper time and the value gets updated every second. Now if I try to change the linux system clock to 1 minutes backwards (i.e.,) if the current time is 19:22 PM I will set the clock as 19:21 PM then the screen update gets struck/hang until 19:23 PM and then it starts working fine. So basically all the timers in the webview code was delay by one minute because I have manually updated the system time.

I have tried searching for the bug fix related to this scenario and found [an bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=119761) link in official webkit bugzilla which seems to address the issue in webkit itself. I tried applying all the patched provided in the child bugs as well but still the issue is prevailing so I am just trying to understand where exactly I need to start debugging this issue in webkit code base.

**Note: I can't update the browser to latest as I need some other library and apps which are depending on wheezy target so updating is not the solution for me.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing the answer here as it can help someone else

Looking into the official webkit bugzilla found the appropriate issue description and its patch as well. After applying the patch done cross compilation again and can confirm the patch works properly.

[WebKit Bugzilla link](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=119836)